# How can I recreate log file and alert log in oracle database

Tags: oracle

How to Recreate of Alert And Log Files in oracle database?

i want to recreate alert log and log file in oracle database, i have one primary database and one standby database, please help.

how to recreate alert log and log file in oracle database?

Comment: What do you mean by "recreate"? If you delete it, the alert log will be recreated with new content automatically. If you mean *restore*, as from backup, that would depend on the type of OS backup software you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Alert Log -

Alert Log can be deleted or truncated at run time. No impact to Databases will be their. As soon as any BG process want to write some log, the database engine will automatically create a new alert log file.

Listener Log -

Steps -
Disable the Listener logging temporarily. (lsnrctl set log_status off).
Delete the listener log file.
Create new listener log file with same name.
Resume the listener logging (lsnrctl set log_status on).